# Maintain source formatting with column reorder Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been importing data from a downloaded report into a working-copy excel workbook for some time now, but someone higher up than me recently decided to change the report that I download for my information.  The easiest solution seems to be to re-order the information in the report workbook before copying it into the destination workbook, but the downloaded report does not maintain its' formatting after the columns are re-ordered, which then carries over into the destination workbook wrong in the current state.

```
Dim X As Long, Letters As Variant, NewLetters As Variant
Dim wbSource as Workbook
```

With wbSource

`Const NewOrder As String = "J,T,U,X,W,K,N,S,AE,AA,AC,AD,F,G,H,I,C,B,AG,AS,AT,O,AJ,AI,AF,M,AH,AO,R,AK,AE,AR,AN,D,E,AQ,Z,AP,P,AL,AB,L,V,Q,Y,A"
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
Letters = Split(NewOrder, ",")

ReDim NewLetters(1 To UBound(Letters) + 1)

For X = 0 To UBound(Letters)
    NewLetters(X + 1) = Columns(Letters(X)).Column
Next

Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, UBound(Letters) + 1) = Application.Index(Cells, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & LastRow & ")"), NewLetters)`

I have attempted to find a way without cut/pasting in the source workbook, but am open to that if that's a more appropriate solution.  Was just hoping there was possibly a way to maintain the source formatting with the current structure.

Comment: i think you should change your approach to this, download the data only and then reformat it as you like in your local copy.